# OpenWrt Makefile include package.mk error

Tags: c, makefile, packaging, openwrt

I'm such a beginner on OpenWrt and Makefiles, trying to demonstrate "Helloworld" example of creating a package but at the package feed update step, from command `./scripts/feeds update mypackages` I get this error

```
Updating feed 'mypackages' from '/home/onur/Desktop/OpenWRT/openwrt/mypackages' ...
Create index file './feeds/mypackages.index' 
/home/onur/Desktop/OpenWRT/openwrt/feeds/mypackages.tmp/info/.files-packageinfo.mk:1: *** target pattern contains no '%'.  Stop.
```

I have `src-link mypackages /home/onur/Desktop/OpenWRT/openwrt/mypackages` in my feeds.conf, "helloworld" C program compiled on `/openwrt/helloworld` directory and below is my Makefile:

```
include $(TOPDIR)/rules.mk
    
# Name, version and release number
# The name and version of your package are used to define the variable to point to the build directory of your package: $(PKG_BUILD_DIR)
PKG_NAME:=helloworld
PKG_VERSION:=1.0
PKG_RELEASE:=1

# Source settings (i.e. where to find the source codes)
# This is a custom variable, used below
SOURCE_DIR:=/home/onur/Desktop/OpenWRT/openwrt/helloworld

include $(INCLUDE_DIR)/package.mk

# Package definition; instructs on how and where our package will appear in the overall configuration menu ('make menuconfig')
define Package/helloworld
    SECTION:=examples
    CATEGORY:=Examples
    TITLE:=Hello, World!
endef

# Package description; a more verbose description on what our package does
define Package/helloworld/description
    A simple "Hello, world!" -application.
endef

# Package preparation instructions; create the build directory and copy the source code. 
# The last command is necessary to ensure our preparation instructions remain compatible with the patching system.
define Build/Prepare
    mkdir -p $(PKG_BUILD_DIR)
    cp $(SOURCE_DIR)/* $(PKG_BUILD_DIR)
    $(Build/Patch)
endef

# Package build instructions; invoke the target-specific compiler to first compile the source file, and then to link the file into the final executable
define Build/Compile
    $(MAKE) -C $(PKG_BUILD_DIR) \
    CXX="$(TARGET_CROSS)g++"
endef

# Package install instructions; create a directory inside the package to hold our executable, and then copy the executable we built previously into the folder
define Package/helloworld/install
    $(INSTALL_DIR) $(1)/usr/bin
    $(INSTALL_BIN) $(PKG_BUILD_DIR)/helloworld $(1)/usr/bin
endef

# This command is always the last, it uses the definitions and variables we give above in order to get the job done
$(eval $(call BuildPackage,helloworld))
```

I know I may have mistake on cross-compile part but I don't think that's the issue that I'm having right now.

When I try to make this Makefile, I get that error.

```
Makefile:13: /package.mk: No such file or directory
make: *** No rule to make target '/package.mk'.  Stop.
```

I can't find any problem like this anywhere. Why it can't even find "package.mk" file.
My directory structure is like, Top directory is `Desktop/OpenWrt/openwrt` and this Makefile is in `Desktop/OpenWrt/openwrt/mypackage` folder. I'm on Ubuntu 20.04

Comment: Then `TOPDIR` needs to be set to the name of the directory where you have this file.

Comment: @tripleee How can I set this?

Comment: The immediate solution is `make TOPDIR= mypackage` instead of just `make` but I guess the script you are running has some way to pass in or configure it to use this information.

Comment: @tripleee That didn't work either unfortunately. "$(INCLUDE_DIR)" is defined as "$(TOPDIR)/include" in rules.mk

Comment: If it's correctly written, you can override that too.

Comment: Ok I guess overriding `TOPDIR` works, but that `./scripts/feeds update mypackages` command still gives error. Do you know anything about it?@tripleee

Answer (score 0):

I found solution to my question on OpenWrt Forum. [Here is the link of thread](https://forum.openwrt.org/t/package-feed-error/101391/2)